# Flash message not getting displayed even after form gets processed

Tags: web2py

I have written the code to create a custom form. It is a simple form which has some textboxes elements on it. When I submit the form, it gets processed but it doesn't show the flash message. I do not want to extend my view from `layout.html`, however I am using the `.js` files that are used by `layout.html`

My code in the controller is as given below:

```
myform=SQLFORM.factory(        
        Field('field1','unicode',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),   
        Field('field2','unicode',requires=IS_NOT_EMPTY()),                     
        submit_button = 'Add',
        formstyle="divs",_id="form1"
        )  
if myform.process(formname='myform',keepvalues=True).accepted:
    response.flash = 'form accepted'
```

The .js files I use in my view are given below:

```
<link href="{{=URL('static','css/payments/css/style.css')}}" rel="stylesheet" /> 
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/modernizr.custom.js')}}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/web2py.js')}}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/jquery.js')}}" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/val/dist/jquery.validate.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{=URL('static','js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{=URL('static','js/genaral.js')}}"></script>
```

Please let me know if I have missed anything important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add the flash message somewhere in the page:

```
<div class="flash">{{=response.flash or ''}}</div>
```

[This](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/views/layout.html#L71) is where it is in the default layout.

You'll also need CSS something like found [here](https://github.com/web2py/web2py/blob/master/applications/welcome/static/css/web2py.css#L91).

Comment: It works and message gets displayed but with no flash effect. It just appears there as text. I want the flash effect. Please let me know how to do it.